# Django, Creating multiple forms for one sumbit button, using crispy and generic views

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I want to create a Person and Assign that Person to a room with the same Form, Model is like Person --> Room using foreign key idPerson

Model Person

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_documento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_tipo_documento = models.ForeignKey(TipoDocumento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default= datetime.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('residentes:detalle', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + ' - ' + self.apellido_paterno

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('id_documento', 'id_tipo_documento')
```

Model Resident

```
class Residente(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unidad_alquiler = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fotografia = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.persona.pk) + '-' + self.tipo + ' - ' + self.persona.nombre + ' ' + self.persona.apellido_paterno
```

Views

```
class ResidenteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Residente
    template_name = 'residentes/residente_form.html'
    form_class = ResidenteForm
    second_form_class = PersonaForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('residentes:detalle')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResidenteCreate, self).get_context_data(** kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            residente = form.save(commit=False)
            residente.persona = form2.save()
            residente.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2))
```

I see the 2 forms as one, but when i submit then i got the error from the form that the fields from the first form are blank.

There is another easy way to do this? Other problem is the fields that have foreign key, can't show the data from db.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't submit two separate forms with one button - HTML doesn't work like that. You need to create a form that contains all the fields that you want, and then handle putting the data into different models yourself. Django provides [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) to help with this.

Comment: I'm not submiting two forms, I just rewrite the GET and POST so i got the control of the commit in the BD